# Why did Gran Trak 10 cost so much?

Tags: history, hardware, atari, arcade

In 1974, Atari released a driving game called Gran Trak 10. The development prototypes had used real car steering wheels and pedals, but it was realized these were too expensive, so they were changed for the production version.

Nonetheless, due to a dreadful miscalculation, it turned out (according to *Atari, Inc: Business is fun*, page 250), the game cost $1095 to produce, while it was being sold for $995, losing a hundred dollars on each unit. This was a large part of the reason Atari ended up with an annual loss of over half a million dollars, earning Gran Trak 10 the title of "the game that nearly put Atari out of business".

Clearly there was too much firewalling between different parts of the company, but I am also curious about the material causes. How did the game end up costing $1095 to produce? It doesn't look that much more complex than Pong - it's described as perhaps the first game to use a ROM chip, but one ROM chip surely cannot have been that expensive - and Pong has been said to have cost $300 to produce. Where did the extra cost come from?

Comment: Do you got any sources for this? Quoting exactly a hundret bucks sounds quite like made up on afterthought.

Comment: @Raffzahn *Atari, Inc: Business is fun*.

Comment: Lies right beside my keyboard - Page? Also, better add it to the question as improvement.

Comment: @Raffzahn Page 250, and done.

Comment: @Raffzahn - Just curious: do you keep it by your keyboard all the time, it just happened to be there today, or did you pull it down from a shelf to answer this question?

Comment: @rwallace Cool. Curt was always a, no, THE prime source for anything Atari, so while I still think the exact number may have been different, I would go with that quote. Sorry, no additional knowledge I can Provide ... and no way to ask him anymore :(

Comment: @davidbak Yes, it was siting beside me, but buried under several others like 'Punch Card Systems' from Lars Heide (absolute recommendation), 'Programming Boot Secor Games', DEC's 'Computer Engineering', an 8080 assembler manual and Maturana&Valera's (German translation of) 'El arbol delconocimiento' (plus a few good VHDL books). So no, it wasn't as ready as 'beside the keyboard' sounds, I had to do a few SWAP operations before it was TOS.

Comment: The Service Manual (https://archive.org/stream/ArcadeGameManualGrantrak10/grantrak10#page/n41/mode/2up) very clearly shows that steering wheel and pedals were part of the machine. You (or, rather, your Atari book) seem to be mis-informed.

Comment: @tofro Err, it seems I did read a different question than you. In mine it sreads _".The development prototypes had used real car steering wheels and pedals, [...], so they were changed for the production version."_, which to me means the genuine car parts were replaced by less expensive replacements, not from real cars. It does not state that no wheel or pedals were mounted.

Comment: @rwallace Sidenote: Thanks for making me check the book, as I found some nice addition to an [answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16963/6659) of another one of your questions :)